# JumpList "close" button or "close" right click option

Tags: windows, delphi, jump-list

I have a jump list (Delphi XE7) and I have all my open forms there so the user can open the one he wants.

I wonder if it's possible (and how to) add a right click option ("close" in this case) or a small X button to the jump list items, that closes the form.

Comment: I think jump lists are the wrong tool for the job. I'd try to do it like e.g. IE does it - see http://webtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/19032010220342.jpg.

Comment: this is what I have right now: http://postimg.org/image/sbzgpk9g1/

Comment: Sorry, image hosters are blocked by our company. :-/

Comment: I agree with Uli. This is an abuse of jump lists. They simply are not designed for what you are doing with them.

Comment: They work pretty well with what I have, the main question is if it was possible or not, looks like it isnt, thanks anyway